# How to reprint codes after a substituiton has been made - python 3.2

Tags: python, decode, substitution

I am trying to make a program where the user has to substitute the symbols for letters in order to get 10 decoded words. I have managed to make the substitution work however when it updates only one line is shown, not all of them. 
Here is my code for trying to replace the symbols into letters :

```
subs2=[]
for word in words_list:
    tempword = (word)
    tempword = tempword.replace('#','A')
    tempword = tempword.replace('*', 'M')
    tempword = tempword.replace('%', 'N')

    addpair1=input("Enter a symbol you would like to replace:")
    addpair2=input("What letter would you like to replace it with:")
    tempword=tempword.replace(addpair1,addpair2)
    print(tempword)
    subs2.append(tempword)
print(subs2[0])
print(subs2[1])
print(subs2[2])
print(subs2[3])
print(subs2[4])
print(subs2[5])
print(subs2[6])
print(subs2[7])
print(subs2[8])
print(subs2[9])
```

However when I try substituting a symbol, this is what comes up:

```
A+/084&"
A3MANA+
8N203:
,1$&
!-MN
.A7&33&
AMA71N
&-&641'2
A))85
9&330M
Enter a symbol you would like to replace:3
What letter would you like to replace it with:h
A+/084&"
Enter a symbol you would like to replace:
```

Instead of reprinting all the coded words with the substitution, it simply shows the first line. 
I was wondering if anyone knows what I am missing or what is wrong with my code.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code doesn't match your output. Also, there's a single `print` statement inside your loop, so of course it'll only print one line. Overall, your code makes little sense: You're iterating through a list of words, asking the user to pick a character to replace (without even displaying the word first, I might add), and appending each word to a list. Finally, when the `words_list` is exhausted, you print the first ten words. What on earth is the purpose of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need move the `input` step out of the `for` loop. Is this what you want:

```
words_list=["hi", "my","name","is"]

subs2=[]
addpair1=input("Enter a symbol you would like to replace:")
addpair2=input("What letter would you like to replace it with:")

for word in words_list:
    tempword = (word)
    tempword = tempword.replace('#','A')
    tempword = tempword.replace('*', 'M')
    tempword = tempword.replace('%', 'N')
    tempword=tempword.replace(addpair1,addpair2)
    print(tempword)
    subs2.append(tempword)
print subs2

#Enter a symbol you would like to replace:"i"
#What letter would you like to replace it with:"j"
#hj
#my
#name
#js
#['hj', 'my', 'name', 'js']
```